# Tools to explore various datasets

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, data-analysis

TL:DR - Do you know of good automated tools to explore a dataset?

Long version: I have a few different datasets to work with from most various areas of business. I wonder if there are good software/scrips that could automatically round up the following answers for me:
Things I would be looking for:

- datatype of a column?
- dimension or measure?
- histogram or count of values in a column
- correlation between measures
- unique key auto-find
- import into a strongly typed data structure

Obviously I'm looking for something more than basic summary(cars). Something that goes through each column and spits out detailed analysis report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very cool active Python package called [pandas-profiling](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling), is exactly what you want. With a simple `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)` it returns a lot of important statistical information about your data, the official documentation says:

> For each column the following statistics - if relevant for the column
>   type - are presented in an interactive HTML report:
>
> - Essentials: type, unique values, missing values
> - Quantile statistics like minimum value, Q1, median, Q3, maximum, range, interquartile    range
> - Descriptive statistics like mean, mode, standard deviation,    sum, median absolute deviation, coefficient of variation, kurtosis,
>     skewness Most frequent values
> - Histogram
> - Correlations highlighting of highly correlated variables, Spearman and Pearson matrixes

Look at their demo [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JosPolfliet/pandas-profiling/blob/master/examples/meteorites.ipynb).
I personally used it few times and it quite nice, BUT it dataset is large (mostly I mean in variable space) it takes a long time to give the statistics. I think there should be an option to even return all these statistics for a subset of features (columns) in case you do not want for all and it is very high dimensional!

Comment: But people don't like so much information in a single line of code...

Comment: this is actually quite amazing and I will use it! Thank you. Accepted as answer, but cannot upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably google and find tons of similar tools, and many of them with a Freemium model.

Most tools would have most of the features you want maybe except:
1) Dimension vs. Measures This one would be a bit tricky; An integer will most likely be a measure, but it could go either way
2) Unique key auto-find: again, it could be a bit tricky; It should be too much work for you to specify as needed.

These two should be relatively easy for a human to label accordingly as needed.

I have tried the following tool and it looks quite promising. (note: I am not associated with the tool in any way)

[Exploratory.io](https://exploratory.io)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to DS-SE :) !

A **very** convenient way of doing this is by utilizing the `pandas.DataFrame` [class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) in Python. It includes methods (and attributes) that perform what you asked:

> "Something that goes through each column and spits out detailed
>   analysis report"

such as:

1. `DataFrame.corr()` for correlation analysis
2. `DataFrame.data.shape` for dimensions
3. `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` to keep the unique elements
4. `DataFrame.hist()` for histogram representation of the data
5. etc..

Comment: sorry, but that's exactly what I'm not asking

Answer (score 0):

I know Facets https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets - which should be nice for a preliminary in-browser preview.

[image]